# How to auto increment number in table column in Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a table in a Word document and would like to add auto numbering to one of its columns. In Excel I would just set the first to `1` and the rest to `=A1+1`, but I can't figure out how to do this in Word. Is it possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to:

1. **Select a column** you'd like to fill in with numbers.
2. Go to **Home** ribbon.
3. Just click **Numbering**.

Numbers should be placed in consecutive rows.
Adjust numbering style, if necessary.

Comment: Thank you so much. Also works for Microsoft Word 2010. :)